# Xcode 6 builds app but won't automatically launch on iPhone after upgrading iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Last Friday, I upgraded from an iPhone 5s to an iPhone 6. Before switching devices, I backed up my old phone ("Skynet") (I know) via iTunes. When I fired up the new iPhone 6, I restored it from backup, so it became the new Skynet.

Now, when I attempt to provision my app, IKApp (not real app name, obvs) to the new phone, it builds, and installs, but won't run. I get this error message:

Could not launch "IKApp"
process launch failed: Security

Here are the steps I've taken:

1. in Developer portal/Devices, added the iPhone 6's UDID
2. disabled the iPhone5's UDID
3. deleted the related provisioning profiles in Developer portal/Provisioning Profiles/Distribution
4. created a new Development provisioning profile
5. installed the app, manually run it on the phone (clicking the "Trust" button)

Still getting the same error message. Halp!

Comment: Have you tried running it directly from the device without Xcode?  Sometimes running an app and telling iOS you trust the developer clears security errors.

Comment: Even after running the app manually on the phone and clicking the "Trust" button, the launch error continues to happen. It installs just fine, just won't auto-launch.

Comment: ...and it JUST fixed itself. Not sure if it took Xcode a second to sync provisioning profiles with the developer portal or what. But jeez. What a frustrating positive outcome. Thanks, @Philip Mills, for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is really a flaw in that error message in that they do not tell what needs to be done. It is as @PhillipMills said, launch the app on the iPhone by tapping it, it will ask it you trust the Mac, click yes. After doing that once the app will run from Xcode.

There are other sneers that cause the same problem with the same solution.

You might file a bug bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Actually, no, it doesn't auto-launch from Xcode, even after I trust the Mac. The app runs just fine if I manually launch it on the phone, but the whole "Build and Launch" process doesn't work.

EDIT: WHAT THE HELL, APPLE. It just worked. Like, without me doing anything different. Thanks, @zaph, for taking a crack at this.

Answer (score 0):

SIGH. Okay. Apparently it takes a second to sync up new provisioning profiles with the Developer portal, or at least right NOW it does, because I literally changed nothing, just flipped off my computer and went to lunch. Came back, was able to fresh install and instantly launch on the new phone using Xcode. Urrrgh! Apple!!!

FWIW, the Developer Portal seems to have been having some problems of late. For example, some of their Member Center pages just won't load in Chrome. You have to use Safari. And sometimes upon submission of a CSR, the "loading" icon doesn't go away on Safari, so you have to refresh the page to see your new cert in the list of certs. These are both new problems, and I wonder if they're in any way related to the provisioning problems I've been having the last couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

Try this slightly different way:

1. In Xcode, go to Window > Devices, right click on your phone, Show Provisioning Files..., click on the provisioning file that may cause problem
2. On your iOS device, go to Settings > General > Profiles, tap on your Apple ID and then authorize this Apple ID